# ProcessStartInfo Verb runas not working

Tags: c#, wpf

What is wrong with the following code?

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = default(ProcessStartInfo);

        startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(SetupProgramPath)
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
            Verb = "runas",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            CreateNoWindow = false
        };

        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

It is expected to prompt for credentials but nothing shows up. The system has the UAC enabled and not supposed to be changed.
I appreciate your help in this one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the point of assigning `= default(ProcessStartInfo);` when you overwrite it on the next line?
`

Comment: That does not seem to be a problem. I can remove it as well.

Comment: Does the program start?

Comment: No. If I disable the UAC, i'll be able to start the program. However, that is not recommended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have worked this out with the following code

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = default(ProcessStartInfo);

startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(SetupProgramPath)
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    Verb = "runas",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
    FileName = "msiexec",
    Arguments = "/i \"" + SetupProgramPath + "\"",
    CreateNoWindow = false
};

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: So you initially forgot to set `FileName` hence no process was started?

Comment: This was the only way that `runas` actually worked for me. Setting it and shell manually like `proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask the user to enter credentials of a different user, then use "runasuser":

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(SetupProgramPath)
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    Verb = "runasuser",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
    CreateNoWindow = false
};

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: They're trying to run as admin, not a user

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, it did not work. It neither prompted for credentials nor launched the setup program. My setup program resides in the network

Comment: I suppose that the value of "SetupProgramPath" is wrong. Just try to use a local application first like "calc.exe". Then try to use the path to your setup application as a string literal. If this works, then try to fix the code that fills "SetupProgramPath"

Comment: Sorry to bother you. It works just perfect when I disable UAC and remove Verb = "runasuser" or Verb = "runas". The problem now is to run program with UAC enabled. I'm able to access the path without error.

Comment: Does it work with "calc.exe" or "regedit.exe"? If yes, then tell us what is special about the SetupProgram. If not, show us a complete and minimal example, because this works over here.

Comment: I have tested this with calc.exe with Verb as both runas and runasuser. It works just perfect. runas not prompted me for the credential whereas runasuser did. The user is a local administrator. I'm wondering what seems to be the problem with the application. The SetupProgramPath is the installation file containing the complete path.

Comment: Try running the application from a local disc instead of from a network share

Comment: Will try but the .msi file will usually be in the network shared path for me

Comment: Do you use a drive letter mapped to the network location like z:\myapp.exe or an unc path like \\myserver\myapp.exe?

Comment: It is an unc path \\myserver\myapp.msi