Make an external exe file to run as administrator in VB.NET
I'm currently working on an application that creates a CMD file. The application also allows the user to convert the CMD file to EXE file using the iexpress tool in Windows. The problem is, my generated EXE file requires administrator privileges to work. I know I can make it run as administrator by changing it's manifest.
Is there a way to change the external EXE file to run as administrator with VB.NET? Is it possible to change the file's manifest? (I mean, the generated EXE file with iexpress)

I'm currently working on an application that creates a CMD file: What's a CMD file?

Windows Command Script (same as .bat file, but used by NT systems.)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469692/verb-runas-not-run-as-elevated
