# schedule a task that runs as administrator privileges

Tags: windows, task, administrator

I am developing a malware scanner for windows that needs to run in administrator mode for any user. Is it possible to schedule a task to run in administrator mode? Is there any code available?

Comment: [Verb = "runas"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43359989/8941307)